Surjectivity of the gradient of a convex function
Question: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth strictly convex function with the growth condition $|f(x)|/|x| \to \infty \ (|x| \to \infty)$. Is the gradient $\nabla f$ surjective?
My attempt:
I could observe that $\nabla f(x)$ diverges as $x$ goes to $\infty$ along with any direction as follows.
By the convexity, it holds
$f(x) - f(y) \leq \nabla f(x)\cdot (x-y)$.
By the growth condition, it follows $\nabla f(x)\cdot(x-y)/|x| \geq (f(x)-f(y))/|x| \to \infty \ (|x| \to \infty)$.
Hence, we have $\nabla f(x)\cdot x/|x| \to \infty \ (|x| \to \infty)$.
This especially implies $\nabla f(ce_{i}) \to \pm\infty \ (c \to \pm\infty)$, where $e_{i}:=(\delta_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq d}$.
When $d=1$, this solves my question by the intermediate value theorem, but I don't know what to do in the multi-dimensional case.
Thank you for any comments.

Adding a reference here to a generalization of this result: It can be shown that surjectivity holds for the resolvent of any maximally monotone operator with full domain (Exercise 23.12, Bauschke/Combettes, Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces, 2nd edition)

The assumptions imply that
$$
\min_x f(x) + b^Tx
$$
is solvable for all $b$. Let $x_b$ denote one solution. Then
$$
\nabla f(x_b) = -b,
$$
and $\nabla f$ is surjective.
